# What does "gifted it straight back" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Unfortunately for the third seed, though, she **gifted the break straight back** and Sharapova also took the next two games to round off victory in littleover an hour.Earlier, Halep booked her place in her first ever final of a mandatory event after outlasting Kvitova after over two-and-a-half hours on court."It was a very tough match today. I couldn't believe that. I came from behind again. She played really well and she was fighting the whole match," said Halep."I'm very excited that I can play in my biggest final tomorrow. I hope that I can control my emotions and just play.
>
> [Source](http://www.afp.com/en/news/sharapova-faces-halep-madrid-open-final)

What does "gifted it straight back" mean here?

Comment: You need to learn what [*break*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_tennis_terms#B) means in terms of tennis. This seems to be one of the main problems in all your tennis-related questions. Maybe you should ask that as a specific question, rather than asking about **four** different words (which will then get closed as too broad).

Comment: @Peter Shore - So sorry, I did not mean to violate the rules here, so I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

To *gift* something means to *make a gift of* something: to *gift something back*, like *give something back*, means to return a gift which someone has given/gifted you.

In this context, *right* means approximately *immediately*. Halep immediately surrendered the advantage of serving which she had just won from Sharapova, making her a gift of the 'break', the change of service.